# Why can't the same program run on different OSes if it gets compiled to 0s and 1s?

Tags: binary, multiplatform

If a program is converted to binary code, or at least machine code, why can't it run on multiple platforms without separately compiling on each? The compiled program runs without the compiler installed.
Even if GUI software behaves differently when built, why isn't CLI code multi-platform?

Comment: There are lots of reasons, the simplest example being that Linux and Windows don't even use the same executable format (Look up ELF and PE formats)

Comment: @FuriousGeorge So basically, the code doesn't get compiled to 0s and 1s but an intermediate which works with libraries?

Comment: Well, it's getting compiled to binary (1's and 0's).  Maybe this will clarify some: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable